# cannot load/fetch mapped collection in hibernate criteria request

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I make a hibernate criteria request on entity and try at the same time to fetch a collection of other items mapped to that entity and get the exception "collection was evicted; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection was evicted".
I use springboot, hibernate, postgres

Here is the main entity

```
public class EntityA {

   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityA")
   @JsonIgnore
   private Set<EntityA_EntityB> association = new HashSet<>();
   
   @Override
   public String toString() {
   
   public void addEntityA_EntityB(EntityA_EntityB enAB) {
        association.add(enAB);
   }
```

And here is the association entity that I cannot fetch in my query

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITYA_ENTITYB")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode   
public class EntityA_EntityB {

   @EmbeddedId
    private EntityA_EntityB_Id id = new EntityA_EntityB_Id();

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("entityAId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private EntityA entityA;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("entityBId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private EntityB entityB;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
```

Here is the other side entity of the association table

```
public class EntityB {

   private Integer id;
   private String name;
```

Here is the request where the line

> "app.fetch("association", JoinType.INNER); "

cause the exception

```
@Repository
public class EntityARepositoryCustomImpl implements EntityARepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<EntityA> findEntityABySearch(List<String> searchs) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<EntityA> query = cb.createQuery(EntityA.class);
        Root<EntityA> app = query.from(EntityA.class);
        app.fetch("association", JoinType.INNER);

        Path<String> namePath = app.get("name");

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String search : searchs) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(namePath, "%"+search+"%"));
        }
        query.select(app)
                .where(cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));

        return entityManager.createQuery(query)
                .getResultList();
    }
}
```

The complete error message is the following

```
collection was evicted; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection was evicted
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : by removing @Data and @EqualsAndHashCode of lombok, the collection is loaded. Hascode and equals of lombok probably includes association information